# ProgressBar с несколько AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Я новичок в программирование. Как прикрутить один ProgressBar к двум и более AsyncTask? В интернете нашел примеры, как используют с одним AsyncTask, а как сразу к нескольким?

```
    GetTaskIgrok getTaskIgrok = new GetTaskIgrok();
            getTaskIgrok.execute();
 GetTaskIgrok getTaskName = new GetTaskName();
            getTaskName.execute();
```

Вот один из классов AsyncTask.

```
 public class GetTaskIgrok extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private Exception exception;

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                String getResponse = get(...);
                return getResponse;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String getResponse) {
            //.............
        }

        public String get(String url) throws IOException {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что именно Вы под этим подразумеваете? При одновременном запуске нескольких AsyncTask правильно стартовать/останавливать ProgressBar?

Comment: да, я запускаю 2 asyncTask и чтоб для них работал один ProgressBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь можно по-разному. Основное: если не показывается `ProgressBar` и стартует `AsyncTask`, то показываем `ProgressBar`. При запуске последующих `AsyncTask` проверяем что `ProgressBar` показывается и если да, то пропускаем показ.

Когда `AsyncTask` завершает работу, проверяем не последний ли он. Если последний, то скрываем `ProgressBar`, если нет, то пропускаем.

Из простейшего - можете завести счетчик. При запуске нового `AsyncTask` увеличиваете. Если он больше 1, пропускаете старт `ProgressBar`. При завершении `AsyncTask` уменьшаете, если будет равен 0, то скрываете.

Answer (score 2):

1) Запустить одновременно 2 и более `AsyncTask` Вам не удастся, если Вы не запустите их методом `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)`. Иначе таски будут выполняться по очереди.

2) `ProgressBar` можно запустить непосредственно до старта обеих тасок.

3) Когда Вы запустили параллельно таски, Вам нужно синхронизировать прогресс. Для этого нужно завести один общий счетчик. Увеличение этого счетчика и обновление UI необходимо синхронизировать, иначе получите гонку данных:

```
synchronized void increment() {
    count++;
    uiHandler.post(...); //update ProgressBar
}
```